# Obtain distance of objects in a collection from camera (programmatically)

Tags: scripting

I'm new to Blender but not to programming.

Can I obtain the distance of objects in a collections from the camera and maybe assign them to a list or a dictionary for further use?

I looked at the docs and have found the `raycast` could be useful but no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raycasting is waaay overdoing it.
To get the distance between 2 objects:

```
loc1 = obj1.location
loc2 = obj2.location
distance = (loc2 - loc1).magnitude
```

If you want the distance to the camera plane, you'll need to look up "point plane distance", it's just math (hint: you can use the camera's forward (z) axis to construct the plane).
To store the objects in a list, do this:

```
my_list = []
e1 = {
    "object":obj1,
    "distance" : distance
    }
my_list.append(e1)
```

To get the distance of obj1, you need to call:

```
e1_distance = e1['distance']
```

e1 is what is called a struct.